# Temporary Table in Bi Publisher

Tags: oracle, plsql, report, bi-publisher

I need to run a a script for the temporary table before running the report in the BI Publisher.
I would like to know the step by step procedure on how to create and populate a TEMPORARY TABLE in the Bi Publisher. I tried to search but there's no clear steps on how to do it. Please give a simple example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the ultimate goal? Why do you want to create a temporary table?

Answer (score 1):

You can create table temporary

--Create table

```
create global temporary table XX_TEST_TMP 
(
ID NUMBER, 
CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(150)
) 
on commit preserve rows;
```

--Create package with function execute insert data to table

```
create package xxx_test_pkg as
   function insert_table_tmp.....
   ...
   insert into XX_TEST_TMP values(....);
   commit
end;
```

In the data source XMLP then add more to execute insert data to table temp.

```
<dataTrigger name="beforeReport" source="xxx_test_pkg.insert_table_tmp" />
```

After that select data on the table XX_TEST_TMP to show on your report.